# Prove or Disprove if the subset is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the Statement :

Let $P$ $\in M_4(\mathbb R)$ be such that $P^4$ is a zero matrix, but $P^3$ is a non-zero matrix. Then prove or disprove that for every non-zero vector v$\in \mathbb  R^4$, the subset {$v$,$Pv$,$P^2v$,$P^3v$} of the real vector space $\mathbb R^4$ is linearly independent.

My Attempt:

Since we are given that $P^4$ is a zero matrix, therefore P is a nilpotent matrix of index 4. $P^3$ is a non-zero matrix then this fact suggests me that $P$,$P^2$ will also be non- zero matrices.

Using the basic definition, consider $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, $\alpha_3$, $\alpha_4$ $\in \mathbb R$ then to check whether the subset will be LI or LD I will form a linear combination and would claim the scalars being "0" (that I just considered above) if the subset comes out to be LI . One more thing I noticed is that 0 will definitely be an eigenvalue, so the time when I will form a linear combination: consider its tiny remnant $\alpha_2 Pv$ then there might be a case for $Pv$ = 0 as 0 is an eigenvalue and this idea comes from the definition itself! This would contradict  because this time the scalars need not be 0.Can we disprove the statement by some contradiction?

BETTER IDEAS INVITED. Thanks in advance :).

Comment: You're on the right track thinking the statement is false. To actually disprove it, you'll need to find an example $P$ and $v$ satisfying the requirements. And yes, it's possible for your example to result in $Pv=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @aschepler said you need to find a counterexample. Pick the canonical nilpotent matrix
$P=\begin{pmatrix} 0 1 0 0 \\ 0 0 1 0 \\ 0 0 0  1\\ 0 0 0 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and then it's quite easy to find a non-zero vector $v$ so that
$Pv=0$.